# Setting JRuby properties within Java code

Tags: java, jruby

I use the JRuby complete JAR to interpret Ruby scripts in my Java program.

Looking for improving its performance, I found some properties: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/PerformanceTuning#compiler_rt_props

But those are properties for the command line JRuby. How can I set them within my Java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `System.setProperty(String key, String value)` to set the properties you provide in command line. e.g.

```
System.setProperty("jruby.compat.version","RUBY1_8");
```

You have to set these properties during start up of your application.so,that there will not be any problem of properties missing